# Trying to write a recursive function in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying a lot but not able to write a recursive function for this.
For Example I have the below list of list which keeps the mapping (not a map as keys are duplicate):

```
[[review1, exclusivegateway4],
[exclusivegateway4, inclusivegateway1],
[inclusivegateway1, T_Review],
[inclusivegateway1, L_Review],
[inclusivegateway1, SP_Review],
[inclusivegateway1, M_Review]]
```

The need is to bypass the mappings which contain string 'gateway'. So as we can see that review1 is mapped to exclusivegateway4 and exclusivegateway4 is mapped to inclusivegateway1 and then inclusivegateway1 is mapped to T_Review, L_Review, SP_Review and M_Review. So bypassing all the 'gateway' string the final mapping should be:

```
[[review1, T_Review],
review1, L_Review],
review1, SP_Review],
review1, M_Review]]
```

I need to make this function recursive as there could be more gateways in there. I know that is too much to ask. But I am missing something in the code.

Thanks,
Nitin
Below is the code without recursion

```
private void decorateList(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mappingList ){
    for(ArrayList<String> list: mappingList){
        String src = list.get(0);
        String target = list.get(1);
        if(target.contains("gateway")){
            listToRemove.add(list);

            for(ArrayList<String> list2: mappingList){
                String list2Src = list2.get(0);
                String list2Target = list2.get(1);
                if(list2Src.equals(target)){

                    if(list2Target.contains("gateway")){
                        for(ArrayList<String> list4: mappingList){
                            String list4Src = list4.get(0);
                            String list4Target = list4.get(1);
                            if(list4Src.equals(list2Target)){
                                ArrayList<String> list5 = new ArrayList<String>();
                                list5.add(src);
                                list5.add(list4Target);
                                listToAdd.add(list5);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    ArrayList<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();
                    list3.add(src);
                    list3.add(list2Target);
                    listToRemove.add(list2);
                    listToAdd.add(list3);
                }

            }

        }

    }

    Iterator<ArrayList<String>> itr = mappingList.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()){
        ArrayList<String> list = itr.next();
        if (listToRemove.contains(list)){
            itr.remove();
        }
    }
    mappingList.addAll(listToAdd);
}
```

And below is the code which I have written with recursion

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mappingList2 = mappingList;
    for(ArrayList<String> list : mappingList2){
    // Below line is calling the recursive function 
    mappingList = decorateListRecursive(mappingList, list);
    }

private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> decorateListRecursive(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mappingList, ArrayList<String> list){
        System.out.println("Count " + count);
        count++;
        String src = list.get(0);
        String target = list.get(1);
        if(target.contains("gateway")){
            listToRemove.add(list);

            Iterator<ArrayList<String>> itr = mappingList.iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                ArrayList<String> list2 = itr.next();
                String list2Src = list2.get(0);
                String list2Target = list2.get(1);
                if(list2Src.equals(target)){
                    if(list2Target.contains("gateway")){
                        decorateListRecursive(mappingList, list2);
                    }
                    ArrayList<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();
                    list3.add(src);
                    list3.add(list2Target);
                    listToAdd.add(list3);
                }else{

                }
            }

        }
return mappingList;
}
```

Comment: Can you write a solution that doesn't use recursion?  That would be one way to start.

Comment: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: This is the code which I have written without recursion

Comment: I am trying to make it recursive but not getting the exact thing to hit. I have created other function recursive the only thing is it has to traverse one more time (I think).

Comment: This is not my homework on which I did not work.I am just missing one concept for which I posted this question. I am still working on it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh, the recursion (as I understand the task is:)

- create empty result list
- call getTerminalSymbolFor(firstkey, firstkey, resultlist)
- getTerminalSymbolFor(String root, String key, resultlist)

  - search in ArrayList for key into value
  - if not found: add root=key to resultlist and return

    - else: return getTerminalSymbolFor(root, value, resultlist) (do recursion)

From your description I am not sure if you start with any symbol, the first or non-terminal ones. But all can be adjusted. I think you might want to pass in a "resolved list" and instead of returning the found one you add it to the lis

BTW: this is horrible inefficient.

Comment: You know what, your Idea helped me in writing this code although I had to add few things in that but It gave me the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

eckes algorithm helped me to get to the solution. I looped through the list and called the list recursively until I found the required Item. Then added that item into resultList.

Thanks